# Tapestry AppModule not added by RegistryBuilder for one project, works fine for another

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7, tapestry

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Tomcat7, Java8, Sysdeo DevLoader and I followed [a Tynamo tutorial](http://www.tynamo.org/Developing+with+Tomcat+and+Eclipse/) to configure the tomcat plugin.

I have two almost identical Tapestry projects.  One app works fine the other won't serve any pages, throwing:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/admin] threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception constructing service 'WebSecurityManager': Error invoking constructor public org.tynamo.security.services.TapestryRealmSecurityManager(org.tynamo.security.Authenticator,org.apache.shiro.mgt.SubjectFactory,org.apache.shiro.mgt.RememberMeManager,java.util.Collection): Realms collection argument cannot be empty.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.services.JustInTimeObjectCreator.obtainObjectFromCreator(JustInTimeObjectCreator.java:75)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Realms collection argument cannot be empty.
at org.apache.shiro.mgt.RealmSecurityManager.setRealms(RealmSecurityManager.java:78)
at org.tynamo.security.services.TapestryRealmSecurityManager.<init>(TapestryRealmSecurityManager.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConstructorInvoker.invoke(ConstructorInvoker.java:48)
... 50 more
```

The problem seems to stem from my `AppModule.addRealms` not being called in the problem app before the security manager tries to get the `Subject`.    In fact it seems that one of the apps enjoys the 'Tapestry treatment' and the other does not.  Here's the one that works:

```
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/bray.xml
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext setPath
WARNING: A context path must either be an empty string or start with a '/'. The path [bray] does not meet these criteria and has been changed to [/bray]
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:53 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'debug' to '1' did not find a matching property.
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:53 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'useSystemClassLoaderAsParent' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
[DevLoader] Starting DevLoader
[DevLoader] projectdir=/home/claude/git/bray/src/main/webapp
[DevLoader] added file:/home/claude/git/bray/target/classes/
...
[INFO] ioc.RegistryBuilder Adding module definition for class com.mydomain.services.AppModule
[INFO] TapestryModule.ComponentClassResolver Available pages (16):
              (blank): com.mydomain.pages.Index
                About: com.mydomain.pages.About
```

Then I see the nice "hello" from Tapestry and my other project (`admin`) comes up:

```
...
Application 'app' (version 1.0-SNAPSHOT) startup time: 172 ms to build IoC Registry, 541 ms overall.

 ______                  __             ____
/_  __/__ ____  ___ ___ / /_______ __  / __/
 / / / _ `/ _ \/ -_|_-</ __/ __/ // / /__ \ 
/_/  \_,_/ .__/\__/___/\__/_/  \_, / /____/
        /_/                   /___/  5.3.8 (development mode)


Nov 05, 2015 11:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/admin.xml
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:58 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'debug' to '1' did not find a matching property.
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:58 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Context/Loader} Setting property 'useSystemClassLoaderAsParent' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
[DevLoader] Starting DevLoader
[DevLoader] projectdir=/home/claude/git/tegu/admin/src/main/webapp
...
Nov 05, 2015 11:45:58 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml setVersion
WARNING: Unknown version string [3.1]. Default version will be used.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.RegistryBuilder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Nov 05, 2015 11:46:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
Nov 05, 2015 11:46:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/docs.xml
Nov 05, 2015 11:46:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml
Nov 05, 2015 11:46:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/examples.xml
```

I expected to see something like this after my `admin.xml` descriptor is deployed:

```
[INFO] ioc.RegistryBuilder Adding module definition for class com.myotherdomain.admin.services.AppModule
[INFO] TapestryModule.ComponentClassResolver Available pages (16):
```

...but instead there is silence.  I can't see anything different in the two apps that would cause one to work and the other to fail.  Where should I look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DevLoader Classpath was wrong.  Fixing that fixed everything.

The DevLoader Classpath did not include the path `/myapp/target/classes` -- and that's where my app's AppModule was (`/myapp/target/classes/com/mydomain/myapp/services/AppModule.class` to be exact).  This can be fixed in `Project -> Properties -> Tomcat` and checking the checkbox for the right path.  The wrong configuration can also be seen in a file next to the project's `WEB-INF` called `.#webclasspath` which spells out the complete path (the relative path is shown in the config page).  After fixing the setup, start Tomcat and `.#webclasspath` should be automatically updated.